# How to add/change a variable across django test functions

Tags: python, django, django-testing

This question might be silly, but I did not find an answer.

I want to add a test function to a class of TestCase to check the completion of the test. For example, the urls were tested, the forms were tested et.al. As such, I would like to have a variable to keep the record of each test. If urls were tested, then VARIABLE["urls"] = True.

Unfortunately, it looks like all the variable were reset in each test function. The message recorded in urls test VARIABLE["urls"] can not been carried on to one other test. Is there any way to have a global variable across all test functions?

**Here are the revised working code**

```
class Test(TestCase):
    test = {}
    to_be_test = ["urls","ajax","forms","templates"]

    def test_urls(self):
        ...
        self.test['urls'] = True

    def test_ajax(self):
        ...
        self.test['ajax'] = True

    def test_z_completion(self):
        for t in self.to_be_test:
            if not t in self.test:
                print "Warning: %s test is missing!" % t
```

The expected result should be:

```
Warning: forms test is missing!
Warning: templates test is missing!
```

Comment: Could you describe why do you need to have these global variables? What's the use case?

Comment: yes, see my example code above. This will make sure I tested everything in the to_be_test list.

Comment: The usual approach is to gather code coverage stats.

Comment: agreed. I was using "django_nose", but it provided too mush outputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a class level attribute?

```
import unittest

class FakeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    cl_att = []

    def test_a1(self):

        self.assert_(True)
        self.cl_att.append('a1')
        print "cl_att:", self.cl_att

    def test_a2(self):

        self.assert_(True)
        self.cl_att.append('a2')
        print "cl_att:", self.cl_att


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What is that attribute is an object that gets created when the test starts?

Comment: `cl_att = []` just below `class FakeTest`